# How to detect start and end of typing on EditText without FocusChange

Tags: android, kotlin, onfocuschangelistener

I have a password EditText in my Login page. I focus on it programmatically and open soft keyboard on onCreate method. And then if CharSequence reaches 6 char long, i call login method to change the Activity.

I want to detect the start and end of typing on password EditText to calculate how long it takes for the user to type the password.

I tried using FocusChangeListener to detect when user starts typing and ends it. But FocusChangeListener does not work on both focus in and focus out. (Since i get start time value when first char typed in onTextChanged method, i don't have a problem with focus in)

LoginActivity :

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val password = binding.password
        val container = binding.container

        password.requestFocus()
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE)

        password.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                if(s!!.length == 6) { login() }
            }

        })

        password.addTextChangedListener(MyTextWatcher(password))
        password.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus -> MyFocusChangeListener(v, hasFocus) }
    }
```

MyTextWatcher:

```
class MyTextWatcher (private val view: View): TextWatcher {

        var tempDate : Long = 0

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            val now = System.currentTimeMillis()

            if(tempDate == 0L) {
                tempDate = now
                startTypingTime = tempDate
            } else {
                tempDate = now
                endTypingTime = tempDate 
            }
        }
    }
```

MyFocusChangeListener:

```
fun MyFocusChangeListener(view: View, hasFocus: Boolean) {
        if(!hasFocus) {
            val result = endTypingTime - startTypingTime
        }
    }
```

Can you help how to detect time when user stops typing?

PS: My methods will be in a library so i do not have control over application.

Comment: What would even be considered "not typing" someone could put the phone down for a second to do something but still intends to put in the full password. the question does not really make sense to my IMO

Comment: @tyczj I also calculate flying time between key strokes but i excluded those parts because they are irrelevant to my problem. So, even if it would be like in your scenario, I will know if there is a huge flying time (meaning they are not typing, waiting or doing something else like you said)

Comment: Why not just do it all in your "text changed" ``TextWatcher``? First time the text changes, use that as the start time *and* the end time. Then for every text change after that, update the end time (since they were obviously "still typing"). So whenever you actually go to read ``endTypingTime`` it'll be set to whenever the last keypress/edit happened (the text can change by things like cut and paste, remember!)

Comment: @cactustictacs Well, it could be a nice solution if i wouldn't have to send a request which carries typing info every n milliseconds. so, i need to know when typing ends somehow. For your scenario, if i gather info for first 3 numbers until nth millisecond comes and send it to server, i couldn't be able to listen last 3 numbers. But since there is one application for my sdk to implement at the moment, maybe i can fix EditText length to 6 and listen until all 6 chars typed. But for long term, i need more appropriate solution. Thanks anyway.